# how to cast sliderView in Kotlin?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Am1bd.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zH42C.png)i did recyclerView consist of photos,when i click on one it's going to move you to rather information about it and more photos shown in sliderView
the problem is i cant not handle array list in "Adapter"

this line of code suppose to show only one photo in recyclerView "ViewHolder"

```
val photo = view.photo.getChildAt(0) as ImageView
```

this line in code should display the first photo in recyclerView

```
Glide.with(context).load(data.urlList).into(p0.photo)
```

================
help!

Comment: What? You show a truncated picture of a NullPointerException, your title implies ClassCastException, then you paste some lines of code. We need complete examples, and copy/pasted logs.

Comment: Very hard to understand what the problem is. 
You need to post more code and the full log cat / stacktrace.

Comment: sorry,i update my question

Comment: Show code and error message as properly formatted text in the question, not as image.